# WCF query returning null

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I've been reading this article http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2011/08/linking-lightswitch-data-to-logged-in.html and I've created a screen to add data to the table SalesPerson.

When Lightswitch creates the screen it adds an AutocompleteBox to select the User. When I run the app it works as expected and I can see the list of users in the AutocompleteBox.

Now I want to query the User table in another screen writing the following statement

```
var query =
  from u in this.DataWorkspace.UsersDomainServiceData.Users
  select u;
```

and the query return nothing.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a *Key()* attribute/annotation added to the property that will be used as the *ID* for the entity?

```
<Key()>
Public Property ID As Integer
```

Without one, you'll get no records. You also need to make sure that the *ID* property for the entity has a value, & is unique.

Comment: Yes I've the key attribute in the property ID and as I said in the 2nd paragraph when I run the app I can see the user's list in the AutocompleteBox but when I try to query the User's table in another screen it doesn't work. That's why I don't understand what can be happening :(